# Can I import 3d cad model with tree structures to A-frame?

Tags: aframe

I would like to know if 3d-cad models can be imported to A-frame with keeping it's structure into A-frame.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "3d-cad" models.

A-frame supports a bunch of 3D formats:

- https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/collada-model.html
- https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/gltf-model.html
- https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/components/obj-model.html

In my experience as long as they are not too complex they render fine.